# watch/track logfile for changes and email for results

Tags: python, logfile-analysis

i am trying to write a script in python to watch a logfile and search specific keywords in the new lines , if found email to specific address else ignore
is there any python module which could help ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use Watchdog to monitor the file for changes, and the built-in smtplib to send the email.

References:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm
https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/